# How can I get Civimail to deliver emails instead of bouncing them?

Tags: drupal, civimail, bounce

I have two separate sites. One is an upgrade from 4.4 to Civicrm 4.7.13 and the second is a new installation of 4.7.15. Both on Drupal 7.53.

Both the same problem in Civimail of not being able to deliver any emails.

(Sending directly to individuals or groups not using Civimail works fine)

When I try to send through Civimail I receive 100% bounces in the Civimail report and all the email addresses are then set to ‘on hold’.

In the Drupal logs, for each email address I get the following 3 errors:

1. Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in CRM_Mailing_BAO_MailingJob->deliverGroup() (line 759 of /[mysite]/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/BAO/MailingJob.php).
2. $backTrace = #0 /[mysite]/public_html/ministry/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(946): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1…[through to #29. I can supply the full details here if necessary]
3. Ignoring exception thrown by nullHandler: , mail() returned failure

Also, when I try and send a test email from Civimail I receive the error message: "Could not identify any recipients. Perhaps the group is empty?" I'm not sure if the two problems are related.

Can anyone help with what may be wrong with my configurations?

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved!

Somehow I had changed the setting in the (one) mail account in Civimail (Administer -> Mail accounts).

The "Used For" field had been set to "Email to activity processing" instead of "Bounce Processing".

So there was no bounce email assigned so the the send was being rejected. Setting the "Used For" to "Bounce processing" fixed the issue.

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in the cool Email Address Corrector extension, to help keep you off bounce lists?

Comment: And remember to set up SPF and DKIM if not already done so

Comment: I'm seeing identical symptoms in CiviMail when submitting mailings and when sending test mails. In my scenario (WP 4.8, Civi 4.7.20), a good email address is already designated for Bounce Processing, so that doesn't seem to be the problem.